# Integrating Jquery with Django

Tags: jquery, django

I want to incorporate a Jquery script into my Django app. The script is a slideshow - when I click on an image, it fades out and a new one fades in. I have two concerns - I don't know how to call the relevant images from my jQuery script. Secondly, there may be an error in my HTML header tag, which is not picking up the correct files or library. I am very new at both Django and Jquery, so your help is appreciated.

Here is my HTML head...

```
<head>
<title>Listings</title>
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'noticeboard/main.css' %}"/>

<script type="text/javascript" href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="{% static 'noticeboard/main.js' %}"/> 
</head>
```

Here is the relevant div...

```
<div id = "image-gallery">
    {% if listing.image1 %}
    <img id = "picture" src ="{{ listing.image1.url }}">
    {% endif %} 
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery script. I'm guessing the `var ImageName` is incorrect. I need to call the relevant image files here, just not sure how to.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageName = ["imgres.jpeg", "imgres2.jpeg", "imgres3.jpeg"];
    var indexNum = 0;

    $("#picture").click(function() {

        $("#picture").fadeOut(30, function() {
            $("#picture").attr("src", imageName[indexNum]);
            indexNum++;
            if (indexNum > 2) {indexNum = 0;}
            $("#picture").fadeIn(50);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: add the static_url to `var imageName = ["imgres.jpeg", "imgres2.jpeg", "imgres3.jpeg"];` so it looks like `var imageName = ["my-static-url/imgres.jpeg", "my-static-url/imgres2.jpeg", "my-static-url/imgres3.jpeg"];`

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageName = [{% for image_obj in image_objs %}"{{image_obj.image_field.url}}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %} {% endfor %}];
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep but doesn't the Jquery script have to be part of the HTML code in order for me to use the above Django templating? They are currently in separate files.

Comment: To get jquery working you have to include <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"> in your html file.You can add your own script in the html itself or write it in an external script and include it in the html.